# How to configure Solr Data Import Handler at run time?

Tags: solr, configuration, dataimporthandler

I have integrated a Solr server with my business application as a full-text search provider. One core is configured to index from a file that is periodically uploaded to a secured location which is accessible by Solr. Is there any way to dynamically configure that particular core to read from the new file without modifying the Solr core configuration manually?

Comment: How do you expect Solr to determine which file to import? Are you going to provide a file name, or do you want it to be determined based on some rule?

Comment: The file name and the directory is persisted in a Mongo collection. However, the directory is fixed and will not be tampered by an external user. A simple rule can be the last modified file in that directory.

Comment: you can try the same by building the query for the data-config.xml where it will check the last modified and will pick up only those files from the path specified

Comment: That would work. But I have no idea what parameters to add. I mean to say that this scenario is different from importing data from a database using delta query right? Also, there is no enough documentation on this as well. Really appreciate an answer here.